# Shutter Unable to capture website

Tags: 11.10, shutter

Shutter is not able to capture website in 11.10. It gives the following error:

[image: Shutter Unable to capture website error]

I changed shutter preferences to save in JPG but apart from the extension the error remains the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That was a bug in shutter but it was fix in the daily builds try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter-testing-team/dailybuilds
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install shutter
```